# Fetching decimal data from Oracle using Sqlalchemy

Tags: python, oracle, sqlalchemy

Executing SQL over oracle using `sqlalchemy`

```
QUERY = SELECT score as SCORE FROM USER1.TABLE1 WHERE id = 101 ORDER BY score DESC

output = []
results = db.engine.execute(QUERY)
[output.append(dict(row)) for row in results]
```

Output:

> [{'score': Decimal('0.9556')},.....]

*score datatype - Number(16,14)*

1. **Even after aliasing it in uppercase, I am getting smallcase output.**
2. **Can we remove `Decimal` in the output?**

I tried casting score as float

```
 SELECT CAST(score as FLOAT) as SCORE FROM USER1.TABLE1 WHERE id = 101 ORDER BY score DESC
```

I am getting output like,

> [{'score': 0.9191699999999999},.....]

Comment: Try `score as "SCORE" from ..`

Comment: @KaushikNayak still smallcase

Comment: Ok, I'm not familiar about how `sqlalchemy` treats the cases. I generally use Cx_Oracle for querying Oracle database. Normally, the SQL engine of Oracle converts all identifiers by default to uppercase.  The double quotes indeed were not needed. So, you're getting it in lowercase means it has to do with the some settings  of sqlalchemy, which is converting it to lower.

Answer (score 0):

Using `Counter` class might be a fine option by adding the code block

```
from collections import Counter
str=output[0]

c = Counter()
for k,v in str.items():
    c.update({k.upper(): '{0:f}'.format(v)})

print(c)
```

to the below part of your original code. This way you get the output as

`Counter({'SCORE': '0.9556'})`